# java setters , not applicable for the argument (void)

Tags: java

Does anybody see what am doing wrong here,  i get this error " the method giveTea in the type Guest is not applicable for the argument (void) , am new to java + my english is bad XD, so what does this mean.

```
Guest alice = new Guest();
alice.giveTea. (new Tea().setName("Roseship Tea"));
alice.giveTea. (new Tea().setSugar(false));
alice.giveTea. (new Tea().setMilk(true));'
```

Comment: Well, that *sorta* looks like Java, I suppose ...

Comment: If you want to use chaining in your setter methods you could return your instance "this" in all your setters..

Comment: Is `giveTea` a field of `Guest` class? Or a method? I can't think of any language that would parse `alice.giveTea.(parameters...` if it is a method (note the dot after `giveTea`). I think there shouldn't be the dot - because it is probably a method.

Comment: We need the code of class `Guest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setter return void, not the instance itself. You should do it this way

```
Guest alice = new Guest();
Tea tea = new Tea();
tea.setName("Roseship Tea");
tea.setSugar(false);
tea.setMilk(true);
alice.giveTea(tea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return type of `new Tea().setName("Rosehip Tea")` is `void` because `setName()` does not return anything. Do this way:

```
Tea t = new Tea();
t.setName("Rosehip Tea");
```

Answer (score 0):

A setter method normally has the return type void. The method giveTea probably a Tea.
What you are doing is creating an object and adding properties together. You should split this or create a constructor that is setting some properties right away.

The latter is a good way, because the Tea object should after its creation be an immutable object. Hence its design should be something like:

```
public class Tea{
 private final String teatype;
 private final boolean sugar;

 public Tea(String pType, boolean pSugar){
  teatype = pType;
  sugar = pSugar;
 }

 public String getTeatype(){
  return teatype;
 }
 ....

}
```